# creating generic functions for multi type arrays in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to create a generic function that can handle actions on slices in Go... for instance, append an item of any type to a slice of that same type. This is simply a generic purpose for a more complex solution, but overall the issue boils down to this example:

```
package main

type car struct {
    make  string
    color string
}

type submarine struct {
    name   string
    length int
}

func genericAppender(thingList interface{}, thing interface{}) []interface{} {
    return append(thingList, thing)
}

func main() {

    cars := make([]car, 0, 10)
    cars[0] = car{make: "ford", color: "red"}
    cars[1] = car{make: "chevy", color: "blue"}

    subs := make([]submarine, 0, 10)
    subs[0] = submarine{name: "sally", length: 100}
    subs[1] = submarine{name: "matilda", length: 200}

    newCar := car{make: "bmw", color: "white"}
    genericAppender(&cars, newCar)

}
```

The code playground is at this [location](https://play.golang.org/p/2mESsiD6XD)

The above errors as follows:

```
prog.go:14: first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After this change you're still getting a runtime error (index out of range) however the problem is that `thingList` is not of type `[]interface{}` but rather `interface{}` so you can't append to it. Here's an updated version of your code on playground that does a type assertion to convert it to an `[]interface{}` in line with the append. In reality you need to do that on a separate line and check for errors.

https://play.golang.org/p/YMed0VDZrv

So to put some code here;

```
func genericAppender(thingList interface{}, thing interface{}) []interface{}  {
    return append(thingList.([]interface{}), thing)
}
```

will solve the basic problem you're facing. As noted, you still get runtime errors when indexing into the slice. Also, you could change the argument to avoid this by making it;

```
func genericAppender(thingList []interface{}, thing interface{}) []interface{} {
    return append(thingList, thing)
}
```

Here's a complete example of the second type; https://play.golang.org/p/dIuW_UG7XY

Note I also corrected the runtime error. When you use make with 3 args they are, in this order, type, length, capacity. This means the length of the array is 0 so when you try to assign to indexes 0 and 1 it was causing a panic for IndexOutoFRange. Instead I removed the middle argument so it's `make([]interface{}, 10)` meaning the length is initially set to 10 so you can assign to those indexes.

Comment: I tried your suggestions [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ecJv730Zrd) and it errors with "cannot use cars (type []car) as type []interface {} in argument to genericAppenderNew". I am not sure this is still possible...

Comment: @gextra in that case you're using the second option and you need to make the type an `[]interface{}` before passing it to `genericAppender` if you use the first example it will take the collection as you currently have it and do a type assertion inside the method.

Comment: @gextra I updated to include a complete example of the second suggestion that runs without errors.

Comment: Surely this is dangerous AF though? I mean any object can be put inside, so how would you access type-specific methods or data?

Comment: @MrMesees I wouldn't necessarily say it's dangerous, it's more a pain in the ass. If you want to write code that safely handles unknown types it's going to involve a lot of reflection and conditionals, it is possible to do, you can't guarantee you'll parse though. It's all up to the person designing the code. I prefer types to be concrete because it makes for simpler, more performant and more consistent code (at run time) but generics allow reuse and some amount of them usually is a good thing. If you wanted a better/safer app, I'd recommend using something more specific than `interface{}`.

Comment: Yeah I came looking for something in the morning and after a few minutes browsing I quickly realised I didn't want to make these trade-off's. It's a pity Go doesn't have some form of pre-compilation processor which would be able to snip around and fill in placeholders to give type-safe generics.

Comment: @MrMesees you just have to define interfaces for that purpose. Go's type system is pretty light weight and therefor not quite as streamlined as some where you can work with `List<T>` but instead you just have to put a heavier emphasis on using interfaces in place of concrete types and you achieve the same kind of generic code without giving up type safety. Using a more specific interface will limit the scope of what can be passed in there to a more realistic and valid input set and then the method can be type safe without doing a huge amount of reflective operations.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer above if you do the following then it throws error. This is what the original question was about:

```
//genericAppender(subs, newCar). // Throws "cannot use subs (type []submarine) as type []interface {} in argument to genericAppender"
```

The trick is to convert your slice of specific type into a generic []interface{}.

```
func convertToGeneric(thingList interface{}) []interface{} {
        input := reflect.ValueOf(thingList)
        length := input.Len()
        out := make([]interface{},length)
        for i:=0 ;i < length; i++ {
           out[i] = input.Index(i).Interface()
        }
    return out
}
```

This you can call the function like this:

```
genericAppender(convertToGeneric(subs), newCar)
```

You can check modified working code here: https://play.golang.org/p/0_Zmme3c8lT

Comment: You are saviour. I had implemented this to accept multiple types, but could not get it work. Your solutions shows how. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

With Go 1.19 (Q4 2022), no need for interface, or "convert your slice of specific type into a generic `[]interface{}`"

[CL 363434](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/exp/+/363434/) comes with a new slices packages:

```
// Package slices defines various functions useful with slices of any type.
// Unless otherwise specified, these functions all apply to the elements
// of a slice at index 0 <= i < len(s).
package slices
import "constraints"

// Grow increases the slice's capacity, if necessary, to guarantee space for
// another n elements. After Grow(n), at least n elements can be appended
// to the slice without another allocation. If n is negative or too large to
// allocate the memory, Grow panics.
func Grow[S ~[]T, T any](s S, n int) S {
    return append(s, make(S, n)...)[:len(s)]
}

// Equal reports whether two slices are equal: the same length and all
// elements equal. If the lengths are different, Equal returns false.
// Otherwise, the elements are compared in index order, and the
// comparison stops at the first unequal pair.
// Floating point NaNs are not considered equal.
func Equal[T comparable](s1, s2 []T) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    for i, v1 := range s1 {
        v2 := s2[i]
        if v1 != v2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

// ...
```

[Ian Lance Taylor](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor) confirms in [issue 45955](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955#issuecomment-972280413):

> This package is now available at `golang.org/x/exp/slices`.
> Per [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-dev/c/iuB22_G9Kbo/m/7B1jd1I3BQAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer), it will *not* be put into standard library until the 1.19 release.
> We may of course adjust it based on anything we learn about having it in `x/exp`.